# What is the derivative of $y=(\cosh\,x)^x$

Tags: derivatives

I have a problem in solving this derivative, so please help me. 
The problem:
$$y=(\cosh\,x)^x$$
I have used log property   $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ln\,y = x\,\ln\,\cosh\,x$

But don't know what should I do ahead. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Diffetentiate both sides

Comment: Use double dollar signs to put the LaTeX in the middle of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=(\cosh\,x)^x$

You need to find derivative of $y\;$with respect to $x.$ So solve it using log-

$ln\,y = x\,\ln\,\cosh\,x$

Now, use the [product formula](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-1/derivative/different-rules-for-derivative/rules-for-derivative)-

$\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\,\dfrac{d}{dx} \ln\,\cosh\,x+\ln\,\cosh\,x\dfrac{d}{dx}x$

$\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\dfrac{\sinh\,x}{\cosh\,x}+\ln\,\cosh\,x $

Multiply both sides by $y$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y\left[x\,\tanh\,x+\ln\,\cosh\,x\right]$

Since $y=(\cosh\,x)^x$

So,

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(\cosh\,x)^x\left[x\,\tanh\,x+\ln\,\cosh\,x\right]$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=(\cosh x)^x=e^{x\log\cosh x}\implies f'(x)=\left(\cosh x+x\tanh x\right)\left(\cosh x\right)^x$$

Comment: It seems that you lost the exponent for the last term ! *Abrazo*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Merci beaucoup, Claude!